# A permutation question

Tags: combinatorics

Can someone help to solve this? Thanks.

Suppose we have N people in a line and we want to sort them according to their heights but not in the "usual" order (i.e. descending or ascending) instead we want N people to be sorted so that the each person is either taller than both of the ones next to him or shorter than both people who are next to him. Of course for person in the beginning or end of the line he only needs to be taller or shorter than the one next to him.

My question is how many ways can we sort them? I suppose to have some iterative formula to solve this but just cannot find it.

Thanks.

Comment: The keyphrase is "alternating permutation". Look it up, and then report back on what you find.

Comment: Ah... Thanks. Searching it now.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: assume that initialy you have people ordered in an ascending order and according to that order we assing to each person a number. Then try applying [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). An atomic event would be in this case that the $i$'th person is surrounded by two either taller or shorter.